# How to have user name a variable that can be used and read by the computer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This project is quite simple. It ask the user to input some numbers, operate some math with them, and then spit it out. However, I want the user to have the option to save their result value, name it, and then be able to use that variable as a number value.
For example:
If the user puts in `1 2 3` and decides to add them up, they get `6`. Then, the user decides to call their sum `var`. I want it possible for the user to input `var 7 8` which would be equal to `6 7 8` because `var = 6`.
Also, this is my first Python project so I apologize if this question seems unusual.

I figured out how to have the result of the user's inputs be recorded as a variable. This is displayed under the `#Save` portion. `numbers` accepts floats or integers and so a string could not pass through (if I am wrong correct me.) One of the problems is that I don't know how to make Python "remember" the value of the user variable in between cycles. I also don't know how to have `numbers` accept said user variable as a number.

```
#Loop
repeat = True
while repeat:

#Input   
    directions = print("Type in some numbers. Use spaces to indicate multiple numbers. Integers, decimals, and negatives are accepted.")
    numbers = [float(x) or int(x) for x in input().split()]
    print(numbers)
    choice = input("Do you wanna choose between '+', '*', '-', or '/' ? Note that values will be subtracted or divided in order that they appear in the list")

#Math
    #Addition
    if choice == '+':
        _sum = sum(numbers)
        print(_sum)
    #Multiplication
    elif choice == '*':        
        one = 1
        for x in numbers:
            one *= x
        print(one)
    #Subtraction
    elif choice == '-':
       if len(numbers) > 0:
           diff = numbers[0] - sum(numbers[1:])
           print(diff)
    #Division
    elif choice == '/':
        self = numbers[0]
        for x in numbers[1:]:
          self /= x
        print(self)
#Saves
    save = input("Do you wanna save the value of the result you just got? Type in 'yes' or 'no'")
    if save == 'yes':
        result = input("Is your result a sum, product, difference or a quotient? Use '+', '*', '-', or '/' to answer")
        if result == '+':
            rename = input("Give your result a name:")
            user_sum = globals()[rename] = _sum
        elif result == '*':
            rename = input("Give your result a name:")
            user_pro = globals()[rename] = one
        elif result == '-':
            rename = input("Give your result a name:")
            user_dif = globals()[rename] = diff
        elif result == '/':
            rename = input("Give your result a name:")
            user_quo = globals()[rename] = self   

#Kill
    kill = input("To kill this program type in 'kill' To continue just press enter")

    if kill == 'kill':
        repeat = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict to store your variables names and values. A dict maps a key to a value, so it should work exactly as you want.

To declare a dict: `variables = {}`.

To set a key/value in a dict: `variables[var_name] = var_value`.

To check if a dict contains a key: `var_name in variables`.

To get a value from a key in a dict: `variables[var_name]` (throws KeyError if there's no key `var_name`) or `variables.get(var_name)` (returns None if there's no key `var_name`).

You can read more about Python dicts in https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp